# В чем разница между void и never в TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

В TypeScript есть два псевдо-типа данных обозначающих "ничто": `void` и `never`.

Чем они отличаются и как понять когда применять `void`, а когда `never`?

Comment: Тут неплохой ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910669/what-is-the-difference-between-never-and-void-in-typescript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Псевдо-тип `never` означает, что функция **никогда** не возвращает значения. Такое может быть, например, в случае если функция всегда выбрасывает исключение:

```
function f(): never {
    throw new Error('Never return');
}
```

Псевдо-тип `void` означает, что функция возвращает `undefined`. Это происходит в случае, если поток выполнения доходит до конца функции, не встретив конструкции `return`:

```
function f(arg): void {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

или когда конструкция `return` используется без указания аргумента:

```
function f(arg): void {
    if (arg < 0) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(arg);
}
```

---

Если говорить о выборе между `void` и `never`, то вам почти всегда нужно выбирать именно `void`. Все дело в том, что `never` используется в совсем уж экзотических ситуациях, поэтому его можно смело исключать из набора типов "на каждый день".

Comment: Хорошее правило, никогда не используйте `never`.

Comment: @CoddWrench  я бы не сказал, что это хорошее правило. Есть ситуации, когда 'never' полезен.

Comment: @CoddWrench аргументируйте.  Есть разные техники.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси представьте себе все функции в проекте которые ничего не возвращают, а верхняя логика строится на обработке ошибок. Я такое видел и никому не рекомендую повторять. Все что я помню про never, он работает не всегда как ожидается.

Comment: @CoddWrench вы уже утрируете) Всегда должна быть золотая середина.

Answer (score 0):

#### Книга TypeScript быстро

*стр 43, 44*

Тип never присваивается ничего не возвращающей функции, то есть той, которая
либо выполняется бесконечно, либо просто выбрасывает ошибку. Стрелочная
функция в следующем листинге ничего не возвращает, поэтому модуль проверки
типов *выведет* (угадает) ее возвращаемый тип как `never`.

Стрелочная функция, возвращающая тип never

```
const logger = () => {
   while (true) { // <---- Эта функция никогда не завершается
     console.log("The server is up and running");
   }
};
```

В приведенном листинге `logger` получает тип `() => never`.

---

Тип `void` не используется при объявлении переменных, а применяется для объявления функции, не возвращающей значение:

```
function logError(errorMessage: string): void {
   console.error(errorMessage);
}
```

Ответ:

> В отличие от типа never, функция void завершает свое выполнение, но не возвращает значение

**СОВЕТ** Если тело функции не имеет инструкции `return`, то она все равно возвращает значение `undefined`. Аннотация типа `void` может использоваться для
предотвращения случайного возвращения программистами явного значения из
функции.