# Как работает never?

Tags: typescript

Прочел очень много ресурсов  про тип `never` в TS [Habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/471026/), [Medium](https://medium.com/@sergey.bakaev/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-typescript-8aa1a0030610), [SO.en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291811/use-of-never-keyword-in-typescript), [SO.ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684964/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-void-%D0%B8-never-%D0%B2-typescript) также посмотрел видео курсы.

Везде говориться одно и тоже что `never` используется в бесконечном цикле, в функции где есть бесконечный цикл, ошибка или рекурсия.

```
function error(message: string): never {
    throw new Error(message);
}

function infiniteLoop(): never {
    while (true) {
    }
}

function infiniteRec(): never {
    return infiniteRec();
}
```

В основном везде стандартные тексты. Но я так и не понял, где можно его использовать? Нету рабочего кода где можно потыкать и посмотреть.

Попробовал использовать бесконечный цикл с `never` как написано и не сработало. Не понял почему? И, что не так?

```
function infiniteLoop(): never {
  while (true) {
    console.log("true");
  }
}
infiniteLoop(); // Potential infinite loop: exceeded 10001 iterations.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип `never` просто помогает typescript понять что функция никогда ничего не вернёт или всегда выбрасывает ошибку. К примеру в таком коде:

```
 const fn = ()=> {
    function infiniteLoop(): never {
      while (true) {
        console.log("true");
      }
    }
  
    infiniteLoop();
  
    return 's'
  }
```

typescript покажет вам ошибку о недостижимости `return 's'` благодаря типу never.

Answer (score -1):

Я это понимаю как функция с never не доходит до конца. То есть while не даст дойти к концу и завершить функцию, а throw просто прервет функцию и не даст ей выполнится до конца.